# Windows 7 domain logon takes too long

Tags: windows-7, login, user-accounts, domain

I have recently installed Windows 7 on my work laptop and am having an annoying problem when logging in to my domain user account.

If I initially try to log on to my domain user account, it takes an annoying 45 to 60 seconds until the "welcome" screen disappears and I can see my desktop.

If I log in to a local account, it takes about 10 seconds.

However, if I log on to the domain user account AFTER I've already logged in to the local account (switch user, or log off and THEN switch user), it takes about 10 seconds as well.

What could be the problem? How would I solve this?

**EDIT:** This is not the desktop background problem. My wallpaper is not a solid color, it's an image.

Comment: Have you tried asking your IT department about it? It's possible there's something particular with your network setup causing this which they may already be aware of.

Answer (score 4):

For computers attached to a domain controller, make sure that the FIRST DNS server listed in the IP Address settings is the DC.  If it is not, this will often times cause the delayed login.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a solid background color? There is a [known bug (and Hotfix)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977346) where that causes the login to take ages, and as far as I believe to know, joining a domain gives you the default blue background.

Try using a background picture and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, my background is an image.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your domain is set up to use roaming profiles.  If that's the case, the extra time for that first log on is spent copying the profile down from the server.